# Replacing multiple regex patterns together

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a long string where I want to replace dozens of regex expressions so I created a dictionary like this:

```
replacements = { r'\spunt(?!\s*komma)' : r".",
                 r'punt komma' : r",",
                 r'(?<!punt )komma' : r",",
                 "paragraaf" : "\n\n" }
```

The above dictionary is a little selection.

How could i apply this to a document of strings? An example string:

```
text = ""a punt komma is in this case not a komma and thats it punt"
```

I tried something like this:

```
import re 

def multiple_replace(dict, text):
  # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
  regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))

  # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
  return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 

  text = "Larry Wall is the creator of Perl"

  dict = {
    "Larry Wall" : "Guido van Rossum",
    "creator" : "Benevolent Dictator for Life",
    "Perl" : "Python",
  } 

  print(multiple_replace(dict, text))
```

But this works only on string replacement and not a regex pattern like my dictionary.

Comment: You would need to iterate the dictionary and then do a sub on each entry (with its replacement).

Comment: do not use `dict` as variable name, it hides the built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate your dictionary, then make a substitution using each key, value pair:

```
replacements = { r'\spunt(?!\s*komma)' : r".",
                 r'punt komma' : r",",
                 r'(?<!punt )komma' : r",",
                 "paragraaf" : "\n\n" }

text = "a punt komma is in this case not a komma and thats it punt"
print(text)

for key, value in replacements.items():
    text = re.sub(key, value, text)

print(text)
```

This outputs:

```
a punt komma is in this case not a komma and thats it punt
a , is in this case not a , and thats it.
```

Note that you probably should be word boundaries `\b` around each key regex term, to avoid matching an unintentional substring.

Comment: Isn't this io/cpu intensive as you apply them one by one?

Comment: @gajapathyp Um...Python's standard regex APIs don't make that possible.  I mean, we can certainly _search_ for some number of patterns, using an alternation, but there can be only one replacement, for each call.  If you have a better way, then you should post an answer, rather than casting doubt on mine.

Comment: @Geveze See the above comment.  I answered not from a performance point of view, but rather using what the regex API would allow me to do here.